# How to change the date format in a file in shell script?

Tags: shell, date, for-loop, sed, grep

I have a file in which are written dates in the following form YYYY-MM-DD. And I want to write a shell script to change the date format into DD/MM/YYYY. 
This is my first attempt that doesn't work

```
#!/bin/bash
NR=$(cat $1 | grep -o '[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]' | cut -d'-' -f 1,1 | wc -l)
for (( i=1; i<=$NR; ++i))
do
    Y=$(cat $1 | grep -o '[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]' | cut -d'-' -f 1,1 | head -1)
    M=$(cat $1 | grep -o '[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]' | cut -d'-' -f 2,2 | head -1)
    D=$(cat $1 | grep -o '[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]' | cut -d'-' -f 3,3 | head -1)
sed 's/[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]/"$D/$M/$Y"/' $1
done
```

I get the following error "sed: -e expression #1, char 51: unkown option to `s'"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need variables for parts of the strings. Sed already remembers parts of the match if you use `\(...\)` grouping.

You can't use `/` as literal and the substitution delimiter at the same time. Either backslash the literal slashes, or use a different delimiter:

```
sed 's/\([0-9]\{4\}\)-\([0-9][0-9]\)-\([0-9][0-9]\)/\3\/\2\/\1/g'
```

or

```
sed 's=\([0-9]\{4\}\)-\([0-9][0-9]\)-\([0-9][0-9]\)=\3/\2/\1=g'
```

Comment: but can't I escape the slash?

Comment: @DenisNichita: You can, but I find it less readable. Check the update.

Comment: how can I escape slash?

Comment: @DenisNichita: Works for me. What OS, what version of sed are you using?